# react-select dropdown to be required

Tags: reactjs, react-select

I am new to react.

I am trying to use below library to use dropdown.

When I added 'required' attribute, it doesn't validate it with the form tag.

https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-select

```
import React from 'react';
import Select from 'react-select';

const options = [{
        value: 'chocolate',
        label: 'Chocolate'
    },
    {
        value: 'strawberry',
        label: 'Strawberry'
    },
    {
        value: 'vanilla',
        label: 'Vanilla'
    },
];

class App extends React.Component {
    state = {
        selectedOption: null,
    };
    handleChange = selectedOption => {
        this.setState({
            selectedOption
        });
        console.log(`Option selected:`, selectedOption);
    };
    render() {
        const {
            selectedOption
        } = this.state;

        return ( <
            Select value = {
                selectedOption
            }
            onChange = {
                this.handleChange
            }
            options = {
                options
            }
            //required
            />
        );
    }
}
```

When I looked at it from the console, it shows that input tag is wrapped with bunch of div. Is there a way to access the input from  Component? or is there a javascript code that I can access to input tag in order to add required directly?

[image]

Comment: i think, you should use library for create form component like 'formik', this library validate your forms

Comment: Does a lot of react developers use this library?

Comment: actually, i use ant design as a component set, that has a form HOC

Comment: There is a temporary solution here https://github.com/JedWatson/react-select/issues/3140#issuecomment-514754657

Comment: I will try to youse formik and see what happens thank you all

Answer (score 1):

I made a tiny example of using Ant-Design form, check that on codesandbox

```
import React from "react";
import { Form, Select, Button } from "antd";
import "./styles.css";
import "antd/dist/antd.css";
const { Option } = Select;

const AppWithForm = props => {
  const { getFieldDecorator } = props.form;

  const handleSubmit = () => {
    props.form.validateFields((err, values) => {
      if (!err) {
        console.log("Received values of form: ", values);
      } else console.log("form is NOT valid");
    });
  };

  const onChange = value => {
    console.log(`selected ${value}`);
  };

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <Form layout="inline">
        <Form.Item>
          {getFieldDecorator("dropdown", {
            rules: [{ required: true, message: "Please select a person!" }]
          })(
            <Select
              showSearch={false}
              style={{ width: 200 }}
              placeholder="Select a person"
              optionFilterProp="children"
              onChange={onChange}
            >
              <Option value="jack">Jack</Option>
              <Option value="lucy">Lucy</Option>
              <Option value="tom">Tom</Option>
            </Select>
          )}
        </Form.Item>
        <Form.Item>
          <Button type="primary" onClick={handleSubmit}>
            Save
          </Button>
        </Form.Item>
      </Form>
    </div>
  );
};

const App = Form.create({})(AppWithForm);

export default App;
```

you should wrap your component with ant-design Form HOC, it's pass a lot of function as a props to your component so you can handle your form with them by using 'getFieldDecorator', 'validateFields'

https://codesandbox.io/s/trusting-microservice-11418

Answer (score 1):

look at this link:https://codesandbox.io/s/react-hook-form-controller-079xx?file=/src/index.js

you have to use Controller

```
import Select from "react-select";
 import { Controller, useForm } from "react-hook-form";
---------------------------------
 const { register, handleSubmit, errors, control } = useForm();

    <Controller
              control={control} 
              rules={{ required: true }} 
              name="citySelect"
              render={({}) => (
                <Select
                  options={citiesOption}
                  value={city}
                  onChange={handleCity}
                  className="basic-single"
                  classNamePrefix="select"
                  isRtl
                  placeholder="استان مورد نظر"
                />
              )}
            />
    
            {errors.citySelect && <p>choise a city</p>}
```

Comment: How can set the placeholder option in dropdown value ?

Answer (score 0):

You should use form library like Formik and use Yup for form validation. Yup has powerful validation methods and is completely supported by Formik.
You can also write your own validation schema.