# Set React Select drop down to be required in form

Tags: html, reactjs, dropdown, react-select, required

Building a react application. Inside a form I can use required on the input field, so if the post back is made on the button it will flag if the input field is empty. This does not work for the react-select.

What am I missing please?

```
<form onSubmit={this.handleSubmit}>

  <div className="field generalField">
    <label className="label">
      Membership <span className="required">*</span>
    </label>
    <div className="control">
      <Select
        options={membershipOptions}
        name="membership"
        className="state-search-choices"
        classNamePrefix="state-search-choices"
        onChange={this.handleDropDownChange}
        value={this.chosenMembership ? this.chosenMembership : null}
        required
        />
    </div>
  </div>

  <div className="field generalField">
    <label className="label">
      Company Name <span className="required">*</span>
    </label>
    <div className="control">
      <input
        name="companyName"
        className="input is-large"
        type="text"
        required
        onChange={this.handleChange}
        />
    </div>
  </div>
```

The drop down is working as expected and posts back the correct selection. if selected. But required is not working.

I have looked at similar Q's such as
[react-select dropdown to be required](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60245821/react-select-dropdown-to-be-required)
but to no avail...

**UPDATE**
So not sure what is happening here, first off please bear in mind I am learning react so it may be my fault causing the issue but I have stripped the class down to the bear basics and created a codesandbox
https://codesandbox.io/s/delicate-sound-srm2fw?file=/src/App.js

Here is my actual code: (I know the codebox is using App and I am using a class..if that makes a difference?)

So it doesnt work in my project it still flags the input field 'Company Name' as being required first...but in the sandbox it works as expected flagging the drop down first...What am I doing wrong?

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import Select from 'react-select';

class MembershipFormPaymentComponent extends Component {
    render() {

        @action
        handleSubmit = async ev => {
            try {
                toast.dismiss();
                ev.preventDefault();

                this.isSubmitting = true;
                const props = this.props;
                const domainStores = props.domainStores;

                //api endpoint call to send email

            } catch (error) {
                this.props.uiStores.errorUiStore.GenerateToastErrors(error);
                console.log(error);
            } finally {
                runInAction(() => {
                    this.isSubmitting = false;
                });
            }
        };
        //populate membership DD
        const membershipOptions = [];
        const option0 = { value: 'Buyer', label: 'Buyer Membership ($75/ month)' };
        const option1 = { value: 'Supplier1', label: 'Supplier Three Membership ($145/ month)' };
        const option2 = { value: 'Supplier2', label: 'Supplier Two Membership ($320/ month)' };
        const option3 = { value: 'Supplier3', label: 'Supplier One Membership ($630/ month)' };
        membershipOptions.push(option0);
        membershipOptions.push(option1);
        membershipOptions.push(option2);
        membershipOptions.push(option3);
        
        return (
            <div>
              <form onSubmit={this.handleSubmit}>
                
                <div className="field generalField">
                  <label className="label">
                    Membership <span className="required">*</span>
                  </label>
                  <div>
                    <Select
                      options={membershipOptions}
                      name="membership"
                      required
                    />
                  </div>
                </div>
                
                <div className="field generalField">
                  <label className="label">
                    Company Name <span className="required">*</span>
                  </label>
                  <div className="control">
                    <input
                      name="companyName"
                      type="text"
                      required
                    />
                  </div>
                </div>
                
                <button type="submit">
                  Submit 
                </button>
                
              </form>
            </div>
        );
    }
}

export default MembershipFormPaymentComponent;
```

[image]

Comment: can you share codesanbox for this, where we can see the issue ?

Comment: Hi thanks for the reply I have provided a codeSandbox but weirdly enough it is working in the sandbox but not on my project...please see my updated post thank you for any help

Comment: yes, I can see that, it's working also with class, I have just copy pasted your code to [this sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/musing-dubinsky-f1t5zl?file=/src/App.js), still no issue

Comment: can you also add `handleSubmit` as well, may be that's causing the issue

Comment: Hi Madan thanks for the reply. I have included the handleSubmit but I dont think that is the issue as I have removed the handleSubmit call to test this and it is still happening

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Html validation is triggered after the onSubmit event. We wont be using the html validation.

React Select required wont work.

Add code to validate the dropdown before api call

```
            try {
                toast.dismiss();
                ev.preventDefault();

                this.isSubmitting = true;
                const props = this.props;
                const domainStores = props.domainStores;

                if(!this.chosenMembership)
                {
                    // alert if not chosen
                }
                else
                {
                    //api endpoint call to send email
                }
```

Comment: Short and sweet thank you Raymond

Answer (score 0):

Heads up: The CodeSandbox does not contain the `MembershipFormPaymentComponent` class mentioned above. So in that CodeSandbox the fields are being validated via the browser. That is why you are getting different results from your actual code.

In the class, you have `ev.preventDefault()` which stops the react-select component from being validated via HTML validation. So what you would get out the box, you are required to write code for it. You would need to write code that validates the select field before it reaches the API call. I would suggest using something like React Hook Form to validate the form. It's a relatively easy library to use. I use it on all my forms.

[Here is another Stack Overflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65211153/how-to-validate-react-select) that is similar to the issue you are having.

[React Hook Form](https://react-hook-form.com/)

Comment: Hi Douglas. Thank you for taking the time to write out your response. In the long run you are probably correct but I am only learning react at the minute and as such am looking for a quick fix. Thank You